# Passing a vector to a function to calculate length in C

Tags: c, data-structures, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct vector
    {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
    };

    struct vector *array;
    double length(struct vector*);
int main()
{
    int num,i;
    double xin;
    double yin;
    double zin;
    char buffer[30];
    char buffer2[30];

    printf("Enter number of vectors:");
    fgets(buffer, 30, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &num);


    array = malloc( sizeof(struct vector) * num);

           for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
           {
               printf("Please enter x y z for the vector:");
               fgets(buffer2,100,stdin);
               sscanf(buffer2, " %lf %lf %lf", &xin, &yin, &zin);

                   array[i].x = xin;
                   array[i].y = yin;
                   array[i].z = zin;
           }

           for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
           {

               printf( "Vector:%lf %lf %lf has a length of %lf\n", array[i].x, array[i].y, array[i].z, length(&array[i]));

           }
}


double length(struct vector* vec)
{

 return sqrt( (vec->x * vec->x) + (vec->y * vec->y) + (vec->z * vec->z) );

}
```

Ok the above code is almost finished it asks user for number of vectors then it asks user for the values of those vectors it then will calculate the length and print it out correspondingly.

I am trying to get some error checking in here but I cannot seem to get it...I looked up every possible return value for fgets and sscanf I just cant seem to get it

Defensive features

FIRST printf-------input should only be a single number greater than 0 and EOF should return a message like printf("enter a number--bye!") so I tried

```
while( sscanf(buffer, "%d", &num) ==1 && num > 0 )
```

but it still works if something like 3dadswerudsad is entered

also when the user is entering the 3 values for the vector if anything at all other than 3 doubles are entered for a vector the program should terminate with a message so I tried

```
while( sscanf(buffer2, "%lf %lf %lf", &xin, &yin, &zin) ==3 )
```

but it doesn't check for these incorrect inputs!!

I am going crazy

Comment: see my answer to your prior question (I think this question should have been an edit to the prior question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right, you need to name the formal and the function and to use it appropriately:

```
double veclength (struct vector v) {
   return sqrt( (v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y) + (v.z * v.z) );
}
```

for efficiency and other reasons you might consider passing a pointer (to a constant vector, since you don't modify it)

```
double veclengthptr (const struct vector* v) {
   return sqrt( (v->x * v->x) + (v->y * v->y) + (v->z * v->z) );
}
```

and then you could later use `veclength(array[i])` or `veclengthptr(array+i)` (same as `veclengthptr(&a[i])`)

You should want to give prototypes (perhaps in some header file) before using these functions :

```
 double veclength (struct vector);
 double veclengthptr (const struct vector*);
```

Notice that for efficiency reasons you might want to declare these prototypes as `static inline` (and give their implementation in the *same* translation unit), so to ask for [inline functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function):

```
 static inline double veclength (struct vector);
```

Take the habit of compiling with all warnings & debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Regarding your use of [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) as `sscanf(buf, "%d", &num)` notice that if `buf` contains `3dxde` it succeeds by reading `3` into `num` (with `dxde` unparsed). You might want to use `%n` in `sscanf` (read its documentation!) or use [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Comment: it might make sense to declare the pointer version as `double veclengthptr (const struct vector* v)` as it does no modifications to it's target

Comment: My C-skills may have become a bit rusty, but couldn't you just declare veclength as `double veclength (const struct vector &v)` and forget about that function that needs a pointer? Or was that one of the things that only work in C++?

Comment: No the formals `(const struct vector&v)` is valid in C++ but not in C. C has no references.

Comment: does my prototype has to change if I do veclengthptr??

Comment: Haha its all the way at the top but I got it working...THANKSS MUCH seriously helped me out

Comment: also had to use the -lm switch with my gcc complier...kept giving me undefined reference to sqrt()

Comment: downvoted because this answer has nothing to do with the question about how to check for invalid inputs

Answer (score 2):

The function could be implemented as follows.

```
double length(struct vector vec)
{
    return sqrt( vec.x*vec.x + vec.y*vec.y + vec.z*vec.z );
}
```

Comment: downvoted because this answer has nothing to do with the question about how to check for invalid inputs